How to set correctly egalax driver for EETI touscreen
I've to connect a capacitive touch layer to an embedded linux SoM base on IMX6.
First, I set the driver for Kernel:

Afterthat, I modified Device tree as follows:
        egalax_ts@2a {
        compatible = "eeti,egalax_ts";
        reg = <0x2A>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio3>;
        interrupts = <4 0>;
        wakeup-gpios = <&gpio3 4 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
    };

Built both and boot my system.
In the bootlog the following appears:
egalax_ts 1-002a: Failed to read firmware version
egalax_ts: probe of 1-002a failed with error -5

Pin I choose for INT stays always LOW, instead of HIGH and goes LOW only when the capacitive touch is activated.
Any solution?

-5 IIRC is -EIO, which most likely the I²C communication issue. Maybe pin control in a wrong state? You also need to check reset pin, power regulators, etc.
